# How to Generate a String from a String Template in Java?

Tags: java, regex, string, substring, template-engine

I want my Java App to read a String from a User, the String may contains some tags, for example :

```
String text = " value 1 = #value1 and value 2 = #value2 ";
int[] intArray = new int[] {4,5};
```

Also the user will enter an array of values to the application. As a programmer I don't know the exact number of values in the String. and I want to programatically generate this String :

```
String result = " value 1 = 4 and value 2 = 5 "
```

to do so I've implemented a method that search for the `#value*` regex and replace it with the first element in a stack of values. it Loops until the program cannot find any #value in the primary String, the problem is that for big Texts, the program take too much time to get executed, which is normal considering the approach adopted.

I've also heard of some Templating techniques using Velocity and FreeMarker, but I've never used them ( any clarification in this point is very welcome ).

**So my question is : what is the best way to solve this problem (shortest execution time)?**

*PS : I don't need code, I want just an approach or API that may solve this issue.*

Comment: shortest execution time? what do you mean with this? also, have you looked at String.format()?

Comment: pft... shortest execution time for some String operation - how many string do you want to convert? 10? 10'000? 10mio?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are creating a new complete `String` at each replacement you will indeed run into problems. You can try building a `StringBuffer` as you go using the helper methods from `Matcher` instead. This should be much faster for large inputs:

```
String text = " value 1 = #value1 and value 2 = #value2 ";
int[] intArray = new int[] { 4, 5 };
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("#value(\\d+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
while (m.find()) {
    m.appendReplacement(result, String.valueOf(intArray[Integer.parseInt(m.group(1)) - 1]));
}
m.appendTail(result);
System.out.println(result.toString());
```

**EDIT**
A number of people have pointed out that `StringBuilder` is better suited for this job. I agree, but unfortunately the `Matcher` API doesn't accept `StringBuilder` as argument to the `appendReplacement()` and `appendTail()` methods.

Comment: If he's worried about quickest execution time then `StringBuilder` is faster but lacks thread safety.

Comment: @Rudi: Added a comment adressing that. You are not the first to point it out. :)

Comment: Learn something new every day. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 3):

There are a huge number of **Template/Expression language** engines to help you with that, `Velocity` and `Freemaker` can also solve the problem, however they can be too heavy for this rather simple task.

As already mentioned by @Keppil (+1), the simplest way is to go with **regexp**. Correct code will take O(n) time.

Just for the reference, for more complex case you can check [Apache Jexl library](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jexl/). Is is pretty light and has clear and simple API. Your case can be solved with following code:

```
    JexlEngine jexl = new JexlEngine();
    Expression expression = jexl.createExpression("value 1 = #value1 value 2 = #value2");
    int[] values = {1, 2};
    JexlContext context = new MapContext();
    for (int i = 0; i <  values.length; i++) {
        context.set("#value" + (i + 1), values[i]);
    }
    String result = (String)expression.evaluate(context);
```

Comment: which is better freemarker vs velocity vs Stringtemplate?

Comment: hard to say, all of them are good libs, it really depends on the usage patterns and how happy you are with the API/features set. if you need html/xml processing, then I recommend also to take a look at Thymeleaf. works perfect for HTML/XML (web pages/rich emails) templates processing.

Answer (score 1):

Use static `String.format(String format, Object... args)` method to format your string with specific arguments.

To find more details on how to propertly create a valid template string please refer to this documentation:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#detail

Comment: as mentioned above ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Java is likely going to have string templates (probably from version **21**, as a preview feature).

See [the string templates proposal (JEP 430) here](https://openjdk.org/jeps/430).

It will be something along the lines of this:

```java
String name = "John";
String info = STR."I am \{name}";
System.out.println(info); // I am John
```

---

P.S. [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/) is 100% interoperable with Java. It supports cleaner string templates out of the box:

```kotlin
val name = "John"
val info = "I am $name"
println(info) // I am John
```

Combined with [extension functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/extensions.html), you can achieve the same thing the Java template processors (e.g. `STR`) will do.